# proof $\lfloor\log n\rfloor !$ is an exponential function?

Tags: logarithms

**Can anyone prove that $\lfloor\log n\rfloor !$ is an exponential function?**

> I've tried a lot but i didn't find anything relating to the solution except e number that i guess it can help.

Comment: $\log{n}$ is never an integer except for $n=1$ so what do you mean by $(\log{n})!$. Exponential function means $\exists a,(\log{n})!=a^n$ or is it a matter of limit at infinity? You need to give more context.

Comment: @marwalix I believe the brackets are supposed to denote the greatest integer function...

Comment: @marwalix I guess the "[ ]" stands for integer part function (some books use this notation)

Comment: I had guessed so this is why in my question I replaced with brackets. I will edit using \lfloor and \rfloor. We still need more context about exponential.

Comment: Another way out is using the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: "Please someone help me quickly"... What makes this question so urgent? Is the factorial of the natural logarithm going to save the world?

Comment: What do you call "an exponential function" ? Mine are of the form $a^n$ for some real $a$ and follow the recurrence $f(n+1)=af(n)$. This is clearly not matched by your expression. Improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log(\lfloor \log n\rfloor!)=\sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}\log k<\int_2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}\log(x+1)\,dx\\
=(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1)(\log(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1)-1)-3\log3+3.$$

Taking the antilogarithm, you get an $O(n^{\log\log n})$ expression.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the solution completely?

Comment: @sajjad: I think I did. Would it be possible to improve your question ?

Comment: i mean that i can not take the antilogarithm and i didn't understand that how did you get to the answer

Comment: Can you help me more??please

Comment: @sajjad : help with what? can you write out the what you dont understand in a different question? antilogarithm is just $e^x$, try to understand the answer?

Comment: @YvesDaoust : is the order of growth $\log \log n$ for $\log n!$ ? can order of growth be smaller than the function itself?

Comment: @Arjang: there is no $\log n!$ in my development !?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, i meant$(\log n)!$

Comment: @Arjang: and where did I say that the order of growth of $(\log n)!$ is $\log\log n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**An elementary disproof**

The family of exponential functions is [characterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) by the following functional equation

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y).$$

For our case, this means that we should be able to show that

$$\lfloor\log(n+m)\rfloor !=\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor !\lfloor\log(m)\rfloor !.$$

Assume for the sake simplicity that the base of our $\log$ is $10$.

For the integers $N<M$ let $n=10^N, m=10^M$. Then

$$\lfloor\log(10^{N}+10^M)\rfloor!<\lfloor\log(2\times 10^{M})\rfloor!=\lfloor\log(2)+ M\rfloor!= M!$$
and

$$\lfloor\log(10^{N})\rfloor!\lfloor\log(10^{M})\rfloor!=(N!)(M!)>M!.$$

So, our function is not exponential.

Comment: neat, can this method be used for logarithmic and polynomial functions? any idea what is analogous to f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) for super exponentials or teteration functions?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=  [\log n] !$ for $n\geq 1.$ We have $f(n)  \leq (1+\log n)!=(\log ne)! .$

From Stirling's Formula  $x!=(x/e)^x\sqrt {2\pi x}\;(1+d(x))$ where $\lim_{x\to \infty}d(x)=0$ we have $$f(n)\leq ((\log ne)/e)^{\log ne}\sqrt {2 \pi \log ne}\;(1+d(\log ne)).$$ Taking logs we have $$\log f(n)\leq (\log ne)^2 -\log ne +\log \sqrt {2 \pi}+ (1/2)\log \log  ne+\log (1+d(\log ne)).$$  For any $k>0$ we have therefore, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  (\log f(n))/\log e^{kn}=(\log f(n))/k\log n=0$$ because $(\log ne)^2/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

So as $n\to \infty,$ the function  $f(n)$ grows more slowly than any increasing exponential function in $n $.

Footnotes: (i). FYI, for $n\geq 1$ we have $0<d(n)<1+1/6n.$ (ii). It is not hard to show there exists $L>0$ such that $L=\lim_{n\to \infty} (\log n!)-( (n+1/2) \log n -n),$ which suffices for this Q . Proving that $L=\log \sqrt {2\pi}$ is more difficult.